# Java set attribute of buildup name

Tags: java

I have a problem. I have the following class:

```
public class Candlestick {
    private double ma5;
    private double ma10;
    private double ma17;

    public void setMA5(double value) {
        this.ma5 = value;
    }

    public void setMA10(double value) {
        this.ma10 = value;
    }

    public void setMA17(double value) {
        this.ma17 = value;
    }
}
```

Then I also have the following array:

```
public static List<Integer> mas = List.of(5, 10, 17);
```

Now in my code I have a for loop that loops through the `mas` list, like this:

```
Candlestick candlestick = new Candlestick();

for (int ma : mas) {
    
    // UPDATE THE CORRECT MA VALUE IN THE CANDLESTICK CLASS
    candlestick.setMA ????

}
```

But I need to update the attribute of the class I am currently on in the loop. How can I prorammatically build up the `setMA()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize Java Reflection.

```
Candlestick candlestick = new Candlestick();

for (int ma : mas) {
    Method setMaMethod = Candlestick.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMA" + ma, double.class);
    setMaMethod.invoke(candlestick, 1.0);
}
```

This code invokes `setMA*` passing `1.0` as a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach to acquire methods depending on a variable would be to use reflection - the [getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) method for example.

However, for your example I think a `Map` with a `Integer` key would be more suitable than every reflection.

That would leave us with the following Candlestick class (main method just for testing):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Candlestick {
    
    private Map<Integer, Double> masses;
    
    public Candlestick()
    {
        masses = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    public Map<Integer, Double> getMasses() {
        return masses;
    }
    
    public Double getMassValue(int key)
    {
        return masses.get(key);
    }
    
    public void setMassValue(int key, double value)
    {
        masses.put(key, value);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Candlestick candlestick = new Candlestick();
        candlestick.setMassValue(5, 13.37);
        System.out.println(candlestick.getMassValue(5));    
    }

}
```

This would also allow you to easily iterate over the masses (or whatever MA is supposed to mean, that's why someone should use proper variable names ;)).